# Hystrix runtime management

Tags: spring, hystrix

Is there a way to control the status of hystrix circuits during application runtime? I'm looking for a solution to open/close specific circuits for testing purposes.

The application is based on a spring stack (spring boot, actuator, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property hystrix.command.HystrixCommandKey.circuitBreaker.forceClosed

ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty("hystrix.command.HystrixCommandKey.circuitBreaker.forceClosed", true);

> This property, if true, forces the circuit breaker into a closed state
>   in which it will allow requests regardless of the error percentage.
>
> The circuitBreaker.forceOpen property takes precedence so if it is set
>   to true this property does nothing.

You can see more of the Hytrix properties here

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration